selecting after a date and comparing between including null
Requirement: To select entries relating to an account where delivered after date x, returned between dates y and z and also where returned is null.
I've attempted to use the following and it selects everything delivered before the stipulated date and then returned only gives null.
SELECT * 
FROM charges 
WHERE ship_to = '$shipper' 
    AND delivered <= '$end' 
    AND ((returned BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end') OR (returned IS NULL));

Where for example $start = '2024-03-01' and $end = '2024-03-31', it is returning:



barcode
delivered
returned




28366
2024-02-15
NULL


27433
2024-03-12
NULL



Where I would expect



barcode
delivered
returned




28366
2024-02-15
NULL


27433
2024-03-12
NULL


22246
2024-02-15
2024-03-10


28843
2024-03-12
2024-03-21



What would be the best syntax to use to achieve this?

The result you get is the result you described. What you "expect" would be ...OR returned IS NULL instead of AND.

Yes, though with AND the results return nothing at all. I had tried OR which gives the above - I will amend my original question.

Please add the sample input data to your question

look closer to see if you application matches the question. I'm not seeing a cause.

This looks like it will be crazy-vulnerable to injection attacks. You should learn about prepared statements instead of using string interpolation.

Also, no repro: https://dbfiddle.uk/micZB3sH

You have conflicting filters in your WHERE clause.
((returned BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end') AND (returned IS NULL))
returned cannot both be between start and end and null. Try an OR
"SELECT * 
FROM charges 
WHERE ship_to = '$shipper' 
AND delivered <= '$end' 
AND ((returned BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end') OR (returned IS NULL))";


Doh! I thought I had used OR. That said, it is still only giving me NULL in the returned column for the results.

Use OR instead of AND
SELECT * FROM charges 
    WHERE ship_to = '$shipper' 
    AND delivered <= '$end' 
    AND ((returned BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end') OR (returned IS NULL))


Doh! I thought I had used OR. That said, it is still only giving me NULL in the returned column for the results.
